# "froala" Editor Removing html tag attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, froala

I am using "froala" Editor for changing inline text,here is the [link](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/)

Every thing is working fine except it removing the div/p/span etc attributes.
here is my function

```
 $('div#eg-custom-toolbar').editable({
      inlineMode: false,
        buttons: ['undo', 'redo' , 'sep', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline']
    })
  });
```

before:

```
  <div contenteditable="true" ng-style="{'color' : styleArr[6]['scopval']}" ng-bind-html="banner_text3" ng-model="banner_text3" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut('banner_text3')" ng-mouseover="hoverIn('banner_text3')" class="banner_text3 ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">HE #1 CONVERSION EVENT FOR BUSINESS GROWTH</div>
```

After:

```
 <div contenteditable="true" class="banner_text3 ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">HE #1 CONVERSION EVENT FOR BUSINESS GROWTH</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify angularJS attributes with the **htmlAllowedAttrs** option.

```
$('.selector').froalaEditor({
  htmlAllowedAttrs: [
                     'title', 'href', 'alt', 'src', 'style', 
                     'ng-style', 'ng-style', 'ng-bind-html', 'ng-mouseleave', 'ng-mouseover'
                    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the list of ng attributes used in my email body templates to the list of allowed attributes in Froala editor.

```
$.FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS.htmlAllowedAttrs = $.merge($.FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS.htmlAllowedAttrs, ["ng-if", "ng-repeat", "ng-show"]);
```

Note that you don't have to copy & paste the whole list again, you can use merge function to do the same.